# Passing parameters in Ruby on Rails (2) Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing

I'm having problems passing parameters (in this case, @plan_id) to the next page (new_user_url).

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  #before_filter :require_admin!, :except => [:show]
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [ :create ]

  def create
    @plan_id = params[:plan]
    if current_user.nil?
      redirect_to new_user_url, :plan_id => @plan_id     
    end
  end
end



class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [ :new, :create ]
  before_filter :require_admin!, :only => [ :index, :show, :destroy, :signin_as ]

  def new
    logger.debug params
    @user = User.new
    @plan_id = params[:plan_id]
    logger.debug "-------------- plan id: #{@plan_id}"
    @plan = Plan.plan @plan_id
  end
```

What I see in the debug message is

```
Processing UsersController#new (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-14 16:07:50) [GET]
  Parameters: {"subdomains"=>["secure"], "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"new"}
{"subdomains"=>["secure"], "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"new"}
-------------- plan id:
```

Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've written your `redirect_to` call, you're passing the `plan_id` parameter to the `response_status` argument. Look at `redirect_to` documentation:

```
redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
```

You probably meant to write:

```
redirect_to new_user_url(:plan_id => @plan_id)
```